# Как вытащить столбец из базы данных в массиве?

Tags: php, mysql

Всех приветствую. Предположим для выборки я использую следующее:

```
$query = "SELECT charvalue FROM charprod WHERE product = 1";
$res = $link->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

у меня появляется массив в котором массивы на каждый элемент из столбца:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким способом я могу все значения уместить в один общий массив, что бы это выглядело примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для решения этой проблемы можно было не мучиться с _fetch_all  а использовать fetch_column    https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-column.php

Comment: либо навернуть array_column($row, 'charvalue')